# Connect to VPN at login Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I am looking for a way to enable me to start a vpn (OpenVPN) connection at the login screen to ensure mounted volumes on my home network connect when I'm out and about. I've not been able to find anything anywhere and was hoping the community could come up with an answer.

Comment: The NetworkManager should provide such a possibility. Either through the GUI which can be started with `nm-connection-editor`, then in the *General* tab. Or use the CLI tool `nm-cli`. It might be easier throught the GUI. In both cases the VPN connection has to be configured through NetworkManager as well already.

Comment: `nm-connection-editor` and .ovpn files are required to be imported via NetworkManager, but it's very easy to set up.